# How can you create a grid in andengine?

Tags: java, android, grid, andengine

I am interested in simple game programming with AndEngine. And I would like to do some basic round based strategy stuff. So I would like to have a top down view to some grid. Every square in this chess like grid should be clickable (touchable on android of course). But I can´t imagine drawing lines and squares is the best solution to do so. I would like to have some kind of abstract object list, which I can extend to different behaviours (one click triggers menu to open, on other field a click triggers an explosion, whatever...).

I have been searching for this in several engines over the years now. It is a hobby, but I would like to find a solution for it. Can anyone give me a hint about how this could be done in an elegant way? Double buffering, rendering and stuff isn´t that important. The important thing is, every square should be an object that gets painted.

Anyone? ;)
Regards.

Comment: andEngine has a few objects that are extension of the Entity class, like Sprite, Rectangle and so on. You can add rectangles as your chessboard and everyone of them can be clickable. It is possible to make their behaviour different for everyone of them. You must be more specific so we can help you

Comment: just a simple example with 3x3 fields that are clickable and change their background color or open a dropdown menu would be great.in a kind of fullscreen app.

Comment: Should every field do the same or different tasks? Did you try anything already? Actually drawing rectangles will be best solution to do what you want... probably.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplet solution would be something like that (lets say that your screen is 800x480 in portrait mode, and I assume that you have GLES2-AC andEngine branch).

in your onCreateScene() method:

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(80, 133, 160, 266, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY){
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //here put what you want to be done after your button was pressed
        }
}
Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(240, 133, 160, 266, engine.getVertexBufferObjectManager()){
@Override
public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY){
        if(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction() == TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
            //here put what you want to be done after your button was pressed
        }
}
```

and you continue 7 more times with changing first two numbers in `new Rectangle(x, y....)` which are coordinates of the center of rectangle(second pair of numbers is the height and wisth of the rectangle). (so bottomrow has coordinates: (80, 133), (240, 133) and (400, 133). Middle row: (80, 399), (240, 399) and (400, 399). Third row you can figure out. Of course it does not give you completely covered screen. This you can achieve by dividing your WIDTH and HEIGHT of the screen by certain numers und use it as a coordinates for rectangles. remember to attach all rectangles to your scene and add

```
this.setOnSceneTouchListener(getOnSceneTouchListener());
this.setOnSceneTouchListenerBindingOnActionDownEnabled(true);
```

and register touch area for all rectangles.

More difficult way would be to create class for example `MyButton.class` that extends rectangle or sprite class that has a methods that will be used when "button" is pressed. It depends on what you really need.